# Android Studio Network Monitoring not Working

Tags: android, android-emulator, network-programming, monitoring

I am running Android Studio 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I want to check the network usage of my application and hence tried the network monitoring tool from Android studio. However, for all the android emulator I've tried, I only get the message

> Network monitoring is not available on your device

Any idea on how I can fix this? What is needed to monitor the network usage? Is this even supported for emulators?

Comment: I doubt that it will work on emulator  as this ( http://developer.android.com/tools/help/am-network.html ) itself says: connect a hardware device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AnyssaK was right. The Network Monitor doesn't work on emulators. Please read their [comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020820/android-studio-network-monitoring-not-working#comment57768865_35020820)

Besides make sure that you selected the correct device in Android Monitor.

[image: Android Monitor. Select the connected device you run your app on]