# Android Studio: Network monitoring is not available on your device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, network-programming, monitor

Today I just open my Android Studio. When I run my Application on Emulator and click on Button, it suddenly crashes. When I see the crash on Logcat, there is empty Logcat. When I go to Monitors is display `Network monitoring is not available on your device`. I am aware of this Problem. The below is Image of Logcat.

**Image :**

[image]

**What I try :**

When I search on similar question on Google. There is one question i found.

**Question :**

[Android Studio Network Monitoring not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020820/android-studio-network-monitoring-not-working)

But this question has not answer by anyone. Also this question is asked by `5 month ago`. So I ask again if any improvement is there.

Any help be appreciated.

**UpDate :**

After 5 minutes later it will display this screen.`The Monitor is disable`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

It is too funny, because this is `NullPointer` error but in Android `LolliPop` device it is displayed as `Network error`.

As I see this error on Android `5.0` means `Lollipop` Version but when I run this in `KitKat` version in `Api 19`. It will give me `NullpointerExeception` because I gave the wrong `Id` to `EditText`.

So I post this answer because when you see this type of error. Check it on all devices because this is not a `Network error`. Although it is just displayed like this in the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

The network monitor only works on real devices, not emulators.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-network.html